# Odoo 8 and child_of filter

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have a Hierarchical categories in Odoo like this

`All
   Saleable
      Accessories
          Audio
          Video
      Components`

to get, for example, all childs of `Accessories` category, i use the code below:
`listcat = self.env["product.category"].search([('id', 'child_of', 8)])`
.
Where 8 is the id of `Accessories`. And as result :`product(8,17,18)`

My problem is when search if Component (id=9) is a child of Accessories, it always gives me 1 (which means it is a child) .

```
exist_in_category=listcat.search_count([('id','=',9)])
```

Comment: just keep in mind the search() method gives and return the object ids while the search_count() method gives us total number of record  within that object

Comment: But... What is the question? You're doing a simple search_count on id = 9  and a search with child_of... To me everything seems to work as expected. Because you'll always find only one element with while filtering on one single id.